# Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine with managed OS disk options

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want the additional configuration options that come with azurerm_managed_disk, and to also be able to use the os_profile and os_profile_windows_config blocks.  It seems I can only have one or the other.  How can I have all the options and abilities of both?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "RTN_webserver01" {
  availability_set_id              = azurerm_availability_set.RTN_AS_Web.id
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = null
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination    = null
  # license_type                     = null
  location                         = var.location
  name                             = "${var.resource_group_name}_webserver01"
  network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.RTN_web01_nic.id]
  # primary_network_interface_id     = null
  # proximity_placement_group_id     = null
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.RTN_thisRG.name
  tags                             = {}
  vm_size                          = "Standard_B2ms"
  # zones                            = []
  # additional_capabilities {
  #   ultra_ssd_enabled = null
  # }
  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = true
    storage_uri = azurerm_storage_account.RTN_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  }

  os_profile {
    admin_password = var.altecadminpw
    admin_username = "altecadmin"
    computer_name  = "${var.resource_group_name}web01"
    # custom_data    = null
  }
  # You cannot set os_profile when using an existing Windows image
  os_profile_windows_config {
    enable_automatic_upgrades = true
    #Windows Azure Guest Agent Service is for communication with the VM host
    provision_vm_agent        = true
    timezone                  = "Pacific Standard Time"
  }
  
  storage_image_reference {
    id        = "/subscriptions/....../providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/Images/images/WebServer2019"
  }

# storage_os_disk name must be the same name as the managed disk name
  storage_os_disk {
    caching                   = "ReadWrite"
    create_option             = "FromImage"
    disk_size_gb              = 127
    # image_uri                 = null
    # managed_disk_id           = azurerm_managed_disk.RTN_web01_OSdisk.id
    managed_disk_type         = "Premium_LRS"
    # name                      = azurerm_managed_disk.RTN_web01_OSdisk.name
    name                      = "${var.resource_group_name}web01osdisk"
    os_type                   = "Windows"
    # vhd_uri                   = null
    write_accelerator_enabled = false
  }
}

# resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "RTN_web01_OSdisk" {
#   create_option                     = "FromImage"
#   # create_option                     = "Empty"
#   # disk_access_id                    = null
#   # disk_encryption_set_id            = null
#   # disk_iops_read_only               = 0
#   # disk_iops_read_write              = 500
#   # disk_mbps_read_only               = 0
#   # disk_mbps_read_write              = 100
#   disk_size_gb                      = 127
#   # edge_zone                         = null
#   gallery_image_reference_id        = "/subscriptions/.........../providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/Images/images/WebServer2019/versions/1.0.0"
#   hyper_v_generation                = "V1"
#   # image_reference_id                = null
#   location                          = var.location
#   # logical_sector_size               = null
#   # max_shares                        = 0
#   name                              = "${var.resource_group_name}_websvr01_OSdisk"
#   # network_access_policy             = null
#   on_demand_bursting_enabled        = false
#   optimized_frequent_attach_enabled = false
#   os_type                           = "Windows"
#   performance_plus_enabled          = false
#   public_network_access_enabled     = true
#   resource_group_name               = azurerm_resource_group.RTN_thisRG.name
#   # secure_vm_disk_encryption_set_id  = null
#   # security_type                     = null
#   # source_resource_id                = null
#   # source_uri                        = null
#   # storage_account_id                = null
#   storage_account_type              = "Premium_LRS"
#   tags                              = {}
#   tier                              = "P10"
#   trusted_launch_enabled            = false
#   # upload_size_bytes                 = 0
#   # zone                              = null
# }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more ... `os_profile` is stuff applies to a VM ... disk is just a disk there is no OS password or user to setup, just like buying an HDD from a store

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using `azurerm_virtual_machine` instead of `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine`?  The former has been superseded by the latter: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine  (See Note at top of linked page.)

Comment: @cdub Yes, as stated in the question, the point is to have all the disk options that come with azurerm_managed_disk..........   azurerm_windows_virtual_machine does not support a managed disk, and has even fewer options in os_disk than azurerm_virtual_machine.

Comment: Also, using managed_disk is more explicit.  The other methods implicitly create a managed disk.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yeah, I'm not asking a beginner question here.  os_profile applies to a sysprepped & generalized image as well.  You would think that you could select the empty disk that you want, and then the image you want put onto the disk, and then be able to configure the OS in the image.  At best I can get two of those three things together.  That's the question; how to get all three.  Thanks

Comment: Terraform can do only what is available via the Azure api ... you can try reaching out to Azure for a feature request but I doubt something like that will be added